# Can Cmd Show Your Location?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, location

Is there a command or batch file that can give me my current location? Please provide code.

Comment: Please Learn The Capitalization Rules Of Written **English** And Don't Misuse **Boldface**. Anyway, that's not happening without an external web service and IP database, or onboard GPS receiver.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As he said **hexafraction**

> That's not happening without an external web service and IP database,
>   or onboard GPS receiver

So you can try this Hybrid script (batch/Vbscript) found on the net :
**TrackLocation.bat**

```
@echo off
title BatTrack Location, By Pierre JOUSSAIN
color 0a
mode con cols=41 lines=14

set vc=%temp%\BatTrack\%username%
if not exist "%vc%" md "%vc%"

set vs=%windir%\system32


:initialization
cls
echo.
echo  Initialization...
echo.
echo   ----^> Checking resources...

set ipwan= Unknown             
echo Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")>"%vc%\ipwan.vbs"
echo Call objHTTP.Open("GET", "http://checkip.dyndns.org", False)>>"%vc%\ipwan.vbs"
echo objHTTP.Send()>>"%vc%\ipwan.vbs"
echo strHTML = objHTTP.ResponseText>>"%vc%\ipwan.vbs"
echo wscript.echo strHTML>>"%vc%\ipwan.vbs"
if exist "%vc%\ipwan.vbs" for /f "tokens=7 delims=:<" %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%vc%\ipwan.vbs"') do set ipwan=%%a                   
set ipwan=%ipwan:~-0,20%


set location= Unknown             
echo Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")>"%vc%\location.vbs"
echo Call objHTTP.Open("GET", "http://www.geo-ip.fr/", False)>>"%vc%\location.vbs"
echo objHTTP.Send()>>"%vc%\location.vbs"
echo strHTML = objHTTP.ResponseText>>"%vc%\location.vbs"
echo wscript.echo strHTML>>"%vc%\location.vbs"
if exist "%vc%\location.vbs" for /f "tokens=7 delims=:<" %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%vc%\location.vbs"') do set location=%%a                   
set location=%location:~-0,20%


:menu
set choice=0
echo 
cls
echo.
echo    ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»   ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
echo    º                º   ³ %date% ³
echo    º    BatTrack    º   ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´
echo    º                º   ³  %time:~0,8%  ³
echo    ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼   ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ

echo.
echo    Your IP wan :%ipwan%
echo.
echo    Location :%location%


pause >nul
goto menu
```